# Agda: type isn't simplified in `with` block

Tags: agda

I'm trying to solve the bonus exercise on page 23 of [this](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~ulfn/papers/afp08/tutorial.pdf) tutorial, but I can't fill in this hole:

```
lem-all-filter : {A : Set}(xs : List A)(p : A -> Bool)
              -> All (satisfies p) (filter p xs)
lem-all-filter [] p = all[]
lem-all-filter (x :: xs) p with p x
... | true = {! !} :all: lem-all-filter xs p
... | false = lem-all-filter xs p
```

If I type C-c C-, in the hole then I get this message:

```
Goal: isTrue (p x)
--------------------------------
xs : List .A
p  : .A -> Bool
x  : .A
.A : Set
```

but I would expect the goal to have type True, since `p x` is `true` and `isTrue true = True`.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pattern match on `p x`, `p x` gets rewritten to the pattern everywhere in the context, but that hole not in the context at the time of rewriting: it appears later and hence `p x` in its type doesn't get rewritten. You can remember that `p x` is equal to `true` using the inspect idiom (deprecated now in favour of [inspect on steroids](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/6420861e30ff37eb2caf8303efd46aa7de2e7eb3/src/Relation/Binary/PropositionalEquality.agda#L106)) described later in the paper, but you can also do the following:

```
lem-all-filter : {A : Set}(xs : List A)(p : A -> Bool)
              -> All (satisfies p) (filter p xs)
lem-all-filter [] p = all[]
lem-all-filter (x :: xs) p with p x | λ (y : isTrue (p x)) -> y :all: lem-all-filter xs p
... | true  | onTrue = onTrue _
... | false | onTrue = lem-all-filter xs p
```

Here you explicitly introduce the type of the argument to `:all:` in the context and hence when `p x` gets rewritten to `true`, the type of `onTrue` reduces to `True -> All (satisfies p) (x :: filter p xs)` as you needed.

Comment: Great!  But why not carry on rewriting things that appear in the context later?  `p x` is still true, so why forget about it?

Comment: @RhubarbAndC, I don't know the exact reason. That equality could be added as a local `{-# REWRITE #-}` rule. But I guess it would be too expensive to track all such equalities: there can be a pretty long chain of `with`s. Also, you actually rarely need to do hacks like above. And I would consider silent implicit rewriting as confusing.

Comment: That sounds fair enough.  I'm far too much of novice at this point to know how big a difference this would make.

Comment: Follow up question: when using the inspect idiom, why can't I pattern match on the equality proof to find that it is `refl`?  The error message suggest that I need to already know that the two sides are equal, but that's silly: it should tell me that, surely?

Comment: `RhubarbAndC`, when you pattern match on `p : x ≡ y`, Agda tries to unify `x` and `y`, but `p x` and `true` can't be unified. The solution is to generalize `p x` to a fresh variable which can be unified with `true`. See the final part of the 2.6 module of the tutorial you're reading for how this can be done. Or you can simply use [`rewrite`](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.PatternMatching).