# With-abstraction and equality

Tags: agda

In the following example

```
open import Agda.Builtin.Nat
open import Agda.Builtin.Equality

postulate
  f : Nat → Nat
  g : ∀{x y} → f x ≡ suc y → Nat

h : Nat → Nat
h x with f x
h x | zero = zero
h x | suc y = g {x} {y} {!refl!}
```

Agda doesn't accept `refl` for an argument.

The main questions are,

1. what am I doing wrong?
2. what is the correct/optimal/established/preferred way of proving stuff like this?

And of course any insights into Agda's behavior are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. Please copy/paste it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[≡-Reasoning and 'with' patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320052/%e2%89%a1-reasoning-and-with-patterns/10386087#10386087) and [Agda: type isn't simplified in `with` block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572464/agda-type-isnt-simplified-in-with-block/38573080#38573080) should answer your questions. [The official docs](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.2/language/with-abstraction.html#the-inspect-idiom) describe how to do what you want, but they don't seem to be too beginner-friendly.

Comment: btw, the official docs seem to be just fine at least for people who care to thoroughly read them through before asking questions. :)